# EF Core - Orchestrate SavingChanges and SaveChanges interceptor / event to keep track of modified entities after changes are saved

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, interceptor

TLDR: How can we orchestrate SavingChanges and SaveChanges interceptor / event to keep track of modified entities after changes are saved for post-processing?

We have a REST API with .NET 7, EFCore, SQL Server and a multitenant approach. We have a new requirement: after entities are saved in the DBContext of a tenant we need to post-process them. All of them. I know this needs to be done after SaveChanges has finished and that we could simply enqueue the entity each time we have a call to saveChanges in the service layer, but unfortunately we have legacy code and that would required to trigger the enqueuer in many places. We want to do this in a centralized place so we were thinking on using three different approaches:

- Overriding SaveChanges method in DBContext
- SavingChanges / SaveChanges event
- SavingChanges / SaveChanges interceptor

We are already overriding SaveChanges so that option is open. Our issue is that we are creating contexts on runtime pointing to different DBs because we have a multitenant software and we need to be able to do that so we have a factory for creating DbContexts and injecting too many things in the DbContext constructor increases the factory complexity. So, SaveChanges overriding is possible but tricky.

All three solutions are mainly the same: Before SaveChanges we get the created/modified entities and after SaveChanges is executed we enqueue them. With overriding SaveChanges this is fairly simple: we get the changed entities and we enqueue after SaveChanges is executed but with interceptors/events it's difficult because there's no linear execution, we have two different triggers (SavingChanges and SavedChanges). One has the DbContext with all the tracked changes and the other has the new state of DBContext after changes are saved: no tracked changes. So, my question is:

How can we orchestrate SavingChanges and SaveChanges interceptor/events to keep track of changes and be able to enqueue items after changes have been saved for sure? Do interceptors work as singletons somehow and so keeping track of modified entities required more work to do or are they instantiated as Transient/Scoped and it's easy to keep track of changes in each request?

Comment: Because you are using SQL Server, would you consider about SQL Server side tracking ?
https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-track-changes-in-sql-server/
Also you might have 
Triggers such as Before/After Insert, Update or Delete or Stored Procedure call that can modify the entity  and EF base you might not be able track them.

Comment: @OnePage is it possible to track the row that has changed to the upper layers (such as service layers outside the DB scope) and do something about it in the application with the same approach I'm talking about? Because this seems informational only and not a way of trigger some action after an entity has been added to the table. Thanks for the different approach but I don't think it's the approach I'm looking for and I also want to answer the question.